# echo: http: panic serving [::1]:45724: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference goroutine 10 [running]:

Tags: go, go-echo

im trying to create an rest api with go/echo and postgres with raw sql but i cant make it work, no idea whats the problem

the console prints the text in the title

recipe.go

```
func CreateRecipe(recipe *Recipe) error {     
    query := `INSERT INTO recipes(title, ingredients, description) VALUES($1, $2, $3);`
    _, err := db.Exec(query, recipe.Title, recipe.Ingredients, recipe.Description)
    if err != nil {         
        return err     
    }      
    return nil 
}
```

router.go

```
func PostRecipe(c echo.Context) error {
    recipe := new(models.Recipe) 

    if err := c.Bind(recipe); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    err := models.CreateRecipe(recipe)

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    
    return c.JSON(http.StatusCreated, recipe)
}
```

server.go

```
func Start() {
    //Setting up echo 
    e := echo.New()

    e.Use(middleware.CORS())
    
    e.GET("/api/recipes", Home)

    e.POST("/api/recipes", PostRecipe)

    e.Logger.Fatal(e.Start(":4000"))
}
```

[image]

Comment: How did you initialize the `db`? Did you initialize the `db`?

Comment: yes i did, thats not the problem, i just didnt show on the code, also i have the type of the json called Recipe that i didnt show it

Comment: Show the full stack trace panic prints, that should point where the problem is

Comment: just to confirm that i send the image

Comment: It is coming from the `Exec` call. It is likely that db is not initialized

Comment: are u sure? i have a table in the db that i created with the connection, i dont think thats the problem

Comment: Can't say for sure (the ?s in the stack trace), but there is nothing else that could cause it in the code you provided.

Comment: Show how you initialized the db

Comment: confirming the image for the db init

Comment: Do not use images. You are redefining the `db` in the function, so the global `db` is never initialized. Use `db, err = ` not `db, err := `

Comment: that was the problem, thank you very much

Comment: sorry for sending a image instead of a code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I initialize the db in the wrong way, I used

```
db, err := sql.Open("postgres", dbinfo)
```

instead of

```
db, err = sql.Open("postgres", dbinfo)
```